# String to ArrayList via org.json

Tags: java, arraylist, org.json

I have this string 
`"["a,rt", "der", "a_rt5%"]"`
and want to convert it to `ArrayList<String>`. Is there any way to do it via the org.json, if not, in any other way ?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I tried to convert it to jsonobject but it req key value structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually your `JsonArray`, so need to work accordingly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[\"a,rt\", \"der\", \"a_rt5%\"]";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            list.add( jsonArray.getString(i) );
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

**Output**

```
[a,rt, der, a_rt5%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "["a,rt", "der", "a_rt5%"]";
str = str.substring(1, sortStr.length()-2);
String[] words = "{"+str+"}";  
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
```

Try out this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to use JSON lib then this is the code which will solve your problem :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "[\"a,rt\", \"der\", \"a_rt5%\"]";
        s = s.replace("[\"", "");
        s = s.replace("\"]", "");
        String[] s1 = s.split("\", \"");

        List<String> sArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        sArrayList = Arrays.asList(s1);
        for (String e : sArrayList)  
          {  
             System.out.println(e);  
          }  

    }
```